# Is it possible to get the returned value of a React component instance?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a `DropdownMenu` component that accepts `ReactNode` as a prop, and `getMenuItems` function that returns markup for that prop:

```js
const DropdownMenu: FC<{ menuItems: ReactNode }> = ({ menuItems, children }) => {
  // ...not important right now
}

const getMenuItems = (itemsToDisplay: string): ReactNode => {
  if (itemsToDisplay === '') {
    return null
  }

  if (itemsToDisplay === 'slimeItems') {
    return (
      <>
        <SlimeItem1 />
        <SlimeItem2 />
      </>
    )
  }

  // ...not important right now
}
```

I can then call them together:

```js
<DropdownMenu menuItems={getMenuItems(someString)}/>
```

and inside `DropdownMenu`, I can see if items are `null` or not:

```js
const DropdownMenu: FC<{ menuItems: ReactNode }> = ({ menuItems, children }) => {
  // If not items in dropdown menu, no reason to render the menu itself
  if(menuItems === null) {
    return null
  }
  
  // ...render the dropdown menu
}
```

So far, so good... But what if I wanted `getMenuItems` to be a component:

```js
const MenuItems: <{ itemsToDisplay: string }> = ({ itemsToDisplay }) => {
  if (itemsToDisplay === '') {
    return null
  }

  // ...same content as the old getMenuItems()
}
```

and later I would use it like this:

```js
<DropdownMenu
  menuItems={<MenuItems itemsToDisplay={someString} />} 
/>
```

In that scenario, is it somehow possible to still do the same thing, i.e., see if `menuItems` prop returns `null` or not?

```js
const DropdownMenu: FC<{ menuItems: ReactNode }> = ({ menuItems, children }) => {
  // menuItems now always is a component instance ... so something like this ???
  if(extractReturnValue(menuItems) === null) {
    return null
  }

  // ...render the dropdown menu
}
```

Or is there some other pattern to figure out if `MenuItems` results in anything tangible, and prevent `DropdownMenu` from rendering when it doesn't - without having to separately run the logic that created those items (or even worse trying to second-guess what items will be returned with a different function)?

Comment: What happens if you try to use `menuItems.props.children` in your last snippet?

Comment: `menuItems.props.children`  contains the value passed to `children` prop when instantiating the `<DropdownMenu />` component. Since we pass no children to it, `menuItems.props.children` is `undefined`. To make it not undefined, we would have to pass children to it, like so: `<DropdownMenu><SomeChild /></DropdownMenu>`